# Why can't I serialize an object to binary format in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have this function to serialize a KnownNetowrks object to Binary Format:

```
const string FileNameBin = @".\knownnetworks.bin";

public static void SaveNetworksBin(KnownNetworks networks)
{
     Stream FileStream = File.Create(FileNameBin);
     BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
     serializer.Serialize(FileStream, networks);
     FileStream.Close();
}
```

KnownNetwork has the following structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class KnownNetworks
{
    public static LinkedList<Network> List { get; private set; }

    public KnownNetworks()
    {
        if (List == null)
            List = new LinkedList<Network>();
    }

    ...

 }
```

And class Network is also `[Serializable]`.

However, when I call the function `SaveNetworksBin`, it always save a file whose size is 129 bytes, even if the parameter `networks` has a list that it is more full or less full. So I think for that reason `LoadNetworksBin` doesn't work (too).

```
public static KnownNetworks LoadNetworksBin()
{
    var result = new KnownNetworks();
    if (File.Exists(FileNameBin))
    {
        Stream FileStream = File.OpenRead(FileNameBin);
        BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
        result = (KnownNetworks)deserializer.Deserialize(FileStream);
        FileStream.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

What's wrong? What should I change?

Comment: Why is that list `static` ? Is that deliberate? It won't work that way.

Comment: Also, LinkedList is probably not the collection you want. Consider `List<>`.

Comment: yup static is the problem without it works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is static and therefore don't belong to the `KnownNetworks` instance you're serializing.